# web page layout problems

Tags: html, css

I am working on web page layouts. I created this one.
https://codepen.io/iamgonge/pen/paOxxb

I dont understand why the .container .left-side and .right-side elements start at the top of the browser and not below the header. Shouldn't the layout out be header->section(hero)->section(one)? I would think that the top of any of those three divs would be underneath the header but they are not. What amy I not understanding here?

```css
body {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  background: #333338;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  height: 800px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  background: #10105f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
}

.main-links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-links a:hover {
  color: #00843d;
}

.main-links a:active {
  color: red;
}

.left-side {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background: #4C4C59;
  height: 800px;
  float: left;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  color: #fff;
  // border: 1px solid #00843D;
  width: 60%;
  ;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px -3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  // border: 1px solid#fff;
}

nav li:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

nav li:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  color: red;
}

.nav-left {
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 96px;
  // border: 1px solid #00843D;
}

.nav-right {
  float: right;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  padding-bottom: 96px;
  //border: 1px solid #00843D;
}

.nav-center {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 75px;
  width: 300px;
  // border: 1px solid #00843D;
}

.nav-right p a {
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-right p a:hover {
  color: #00843d;
}

.nav-right p {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background: #080853;
}

.right-side {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  background: #4C4C59;
  height: 800px;
  float: right;
}

.rss-title,
.rss-date {
  margin: 0px!important;
}

.rss-feed {
  margin: 10px 5px 20px 0px;
}

.rss-date {
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.hero,
.one {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.success {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20%;
  font-size: 69px;
  color: #00843d;
  //  margin-left: auto;
  // margin-right: auto;
}

.success:hover {
  font-size: 71px;
}

#timestamp {
  margin: 10px 5px 20px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#timestamp,
.rss-feed {
  background: #080853;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 110px;
}

@media (min-width:1530px) {}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="nav-left">
      <div id="timestamp"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right"></div>
    <div class="nav-center"></div>

    <nav>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="main-links"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li class="main-links"><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li class="main-links"><a href="#">projects</a></li>
        <li class="main-links"><a href="#">portal</a></li>
        <li class="main-links"><a href="#">links</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <section="hero">
    <div class="left-side"></div>
    <div class="right-side"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="success"></div>
    </div>
    <!--***Container***-->
  </section>
  <section class="one"></section>
</body>
```

Comment: Not the complete answer you are looking for; but shouldn't `<section="hero">` be `<section class="hero">` for starters?

Comment: When you give something an absolute or fixed position it gets removed from the normal flow of the page, so other elements can lay on top of or under them if they overlap. To avoid this, use positioning more judiciously.

Comment: thanks for replying, I want the header to be fixed.So do I have to set the top position for the hero section? Is there a way to have a fixed header and have the sections following it follow the flow of the page?

Comment: Yeah, very possible. What are you looking for the layout to be and I'll go into JSfiddle and do something?

Comment: well Id like the layout to resemble what I have on codepen but Id everything to start after the fixed header. Basically I id like to see how to start a natural flow following the fixed header. Ill be adding more sections and want all elements within a section to be contained to that section, no overlapping.

Comment: I don't see a codepen link here

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added it. It's there now. Also I just solved it I think but would like to know if there's a better way. I put everything after the header in a wrapper, set it to absolute and set the top at 150px. I'd like to see if there's other ways of solving this or laying this out more efficiently.

Comment: I'll look at this when OT is over...

Comment: This works fine enough as long as your header is always going to be 150px. I did notice that your main content scrolls over your fixed header. If you don't want that, give your header a z-index: 2. Also, use /* and */ to comment out in your CSS.

Comment: what if header isnt set to 150? How would I go about it then?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you have applied `position: fixed;` to your `<header>` tag. When you do this you must account for the height of the header and push down other elements to restore the layout.